# Manage memory usage in Navigation Stack

Tags: ios, swift

I've noticed when opening multiple instances of a view, my memory continues to climb with the more views that the user opens. If the user starts to hit back the memory usage drops with each view controller closing. However, depending on whatever the user is doing he can open 20+ view controllers, how can I manage the memory utilisation? The view controller has a collection view with a header view playing a video and collection view cells displaying images. I need all those views loaded in the background so they can be quickly loaded when the user hits back.

Comment: Are you asking how to manage memory if the number of view controllers in the navigation stack is too large?

Comment: That seems to be too generic a question, maybe you need to redesign the app so you wouldn't have 20+ view controllers in the background, maybe you need to change how you need to change your data so it wouldn't use too much memory, maybe you need to track your view controllers and unload data  when they've got more than 1 or 2 view controllers on top etc.